# Error registering data from android to phpmyadmin

Tags: java, php, android

I'm neophyte programming in Android Studio, I look for a solution to this code, before I worked entering the data entered in android to a db in phpmyadmin however now I do not know where the error is, the only thing I did was adding some more fields to the php file. What I have so far is the following:

**Main2Activity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Objects;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener   {

    private static final String TAG = "Main2Activity";
    private EditText nd, date, dbruto, veintiuno, subt1, descuento5, subt2,  descuento10, descuento15, subt3, descuento2, subt4,  descuento1, tdescuento, dtotal;
    private RequestQueue rq;
    private JsonRequest jrq;
    private Button rdiezmo;

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener nDateSetListener;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rdiezmo = findViewById(R.id.btnrd);
        date=findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                int year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day=calendar.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Main2Activity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        nDateSetListener,
                        year,month,day);
                Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        nDateSetListener = new
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                        month = month +1;
                        Log.d(TAG,"onDateSet: mm/dd/yyy: "+ year +"-"+month+"-"+day);
                        String ndate = year + "-"+month+"-"+day;
                        date.setText(ndate);
                    }
                };

        TextView txtBienvenido = findViewById(R.id.txtbienvenido);
        txtBienvenido.setText("¡Por favor! Ingrese los datos");
        nd = findViewById(R.id.txtndom);
        dbruto = findViewById(R.id.txtdbruto);
        String dato = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
        dbruto.setText(dato);
        veintiuno = findViewById(R.id.txtd21);
        subt1 = findViewById(R.id.txts1);
        descuento5 = findViewById(R.id.desc5);
        subt2 = findViewById(R.id.txts2);
        descuento10 = findViewById(R.id.desc10);
        descuento15 = findViewById(R.id.desc15);
        subt3 = findViewById(R.id.txts3);
        descuento2 = findViewById(R.id.desc2);
        subt4 = findViewById(R.id.txts4);
        descuento1 = findViewById(R.id.desc1);
        tdescuento = findViewById(R.id.txtdesc);
        dtotal = findViewById(R.id.txtdiezmob);
        findViewById(R.id.btncd).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btnrd).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btncd:
                //Calcula descuento 21%
                float v21 = Float.parseFloat((dbruto.getText().toString()));
                float d21 = (v21 * 21) / 100;
                String r1 = String.valueOf((double) d21);
                veintiuno.setText((r1));

                //Calcula subtotal 1
                float s1 = v21 - d21;
                String r2 = String.valueOf((double) s1);
                subt1.setText((r2));

                //Calcula descuento 5%
                float d5 = (s1 * 5) / 100;
                String r3 = String.valueOf((double) d5);
                descuento5.setText((r3));

                //Calcula subtotal 2
                float s2 = s1 - d5;
                String r4 = String.valueOf((double) s2);
                subt2.setText((r4));

                //Como se está calculando el 5% este valor es 0
                float d10 = 0;
                String r5 = String.valueOf((double) d10);
                descuento10.setText((r5));

                //Como se está calculando el 5% este valor es 0
                float d15 = 0;
                String r6 = String.valueOf((double) d15);
                descuento15.setText((r6));

                //Como se está calculando el 5% este valor es 0
                float s3 = 0;
                String r7 = String.valueOf((double) s3);
                subt3.setText((r7));

                //Calcula descuento 2%
                float d2 = (s2 * 2) / 100;
                String r8 = String.valueOf((double) d2);
                descuento2.setText((r8));

                //Calcula subtotal 4
                float s4 = s2 - d2;
                String r9 = String.valueOf((double) s4);
                subt4.setText((r9));


                //Calcula descuento 1%
                float d1 = (s4 * 1) / 100;
                String r10 = String.valueOf((double) d1);
                descuento1.setText((r10));

                //Calcula total descuento
                float tdesc = d21 + d5 + d2 + d1;
                String r11 = String.valueOf((double) tdesc);
                tdescuento.setText((r11));

                //Calcula diezmo neto
                float dneto = s4 - d1;
                String r12 = String.valueOf((double) dneto);
                dtotal.setText((r12));

                break;

            case R.id.btnrd:

                String url =
                        "https://ipucsegundaalgarrobo.000webhostapp.com/diezmo15.php?nd=" + nd.getText().toString() + "&fd=" + date.getText().toString() +
                                "&db=" + dbruto.getText().toString() + "&sb1=" + dbruto.getText().toString() + "&d1=" + veintiuno.getText().toString() +
                                "&sb2=" + subt1.getText().toString() + "&d2=" + descuento5.getText().toString() + "&sb3=" + subt2.getText().toString() +
                                "&d3=" + descuento10.getText().toString() + "&d4=" + descuento15.getText().toString() + "&sb4=" + subt3.getText().toString() +
                                "&d5=" + descuento2.getText().toString() + "&sb5=" + subt4.getText().toString() + "&d6=" + descuento1.getText().toString() +
                                "&td=" + tdescuento.getText().toString() + "&dn=" + dtotal.getText().toString();

                jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
                rq.add(jrq);
                Log.i(" URL ", " Url de petición " +url);
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo registrar los datos" + error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha registrado los datos correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        limpiarRegistros();
    }
    private void limpiarRegistros() {
        nd.setText("");
        date.setText("");
        dbruto.setText("");
        veintiuno.setText("");
        subt1.setText("");
        descuento5.setText("");
        subt2.setText("");
        descuento10.setText("");
        descuento15.setText("");
        descuento2.setText("");
        subt3.setText("");
        subt4.setText("");
        descuento1.setText("");
        tdescuento.setText("");
        dtotal.setText("");
    }
}
```

The file diezmo15.php is this:

```
<?php

$json=array();
    if(isset($_GET["nd"]) && ($_GET["fd"]) &&($_GET["db"]) && ($_GET["sb1"]) && ($_GET["d1"]) && ($_GET["sb2"]) && ($_GET["d2"]) && ($_GET["sb3"]) && ($_GET["d3"]) && ($_GET["d4"]) && ($_GET["sb4"]) && ($_GET["d5"]) && ($_GET["sb5"]) && ($_GET["d6"]) && ($_GET["td"]) && isset($_GET["dn"])){
        $nd = $_GET['nd'];
        $fd = $_GET['fd'];
        $db = $_GET['db'];
        $sb1 = $_GET['sb1'];
        $d1 = $_GET['d1'];
        $sb2 = $_GET['sb2'];
        $d2 = $_GET['d2'];
        $sb3 = $_GET['sb3'];
        $d3 = $_GET['d3'];
        $d4 = $_GET['d4'];
        $sb4 = $_GET['sb4'];
        $d5 = $_GET['d5'];
        $sb5 = $_GET['sb5'];
        $d6 = $_GET['d6'];
        $td = $_GET['td'];
        $dn = $_GET['dn'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect 
("localhost","tubd","tucontrasena","tutabla" ) or die  
("Sin Conexion");

        $consulta="INSERT INTO diezmos15(ndom, fdom, dbru, subt1,  
desc21, subt2, desc5, subt3, desc10, desc15, subt4, desc2, subt5, desc1, tdesc, dneto) 

VALUES  
('{$nd}','{$fd}','{$db}','{$sb1}','{$d1}','{$sb2}','{$d2}','{$sb3}','{$d3}','{$d4}','{$sb4}','{$d5}','{$sb5}','{$d6}','{$td}','{$dn}')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        if($consulta){
           $consulta="SELECT * FROM diezmos  WHERE 

ndom='{$nd}'";
           $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

            if($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                $json['datos'][]=$reg;
            }
            mysqli_close($conexion);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
        else{
            $results['nd']='';
            $results['fd']='';
            $results['db']='';
            $results['sb1']='';
            $results['d1']='';
            $results['sb2']='';
            $results['d2']='';
            $results['sb3']='';
            $results['d3']='';
            $results['d4']='';
            $results['sb4']='';         
            $results['d5']='';
            $results['sb5']='';
            $results['d6']='';
            $results['td']='';
            $results['dn']='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
    }
    else{   
            $results['nd']='';
            $results['fd']='';
            $results['db']='';
            $results['sb1']='';
            $results['d1']='';
            $results['sb2']='';
            $results['d2']='';
            $results['sb3']='';
            $results['d3']='';
            $results['d4']='';
            $results['sb4']='';         
            $results['d5']='';
            $results['sb5']='';
            $results['d6']='';
            $results['td']='';
            $results['dn']='';
            $json['datos'][]=$results;
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
?>
```

When you press the button "register tithe" what it does is take the data entered in each of the fields and send them to the bd located in phpmyadmin, however this no longer works, it does not record the data but it sends me the following error:

> com.android.volley.parseerror: org.json.jsonexception: value [] of type org.json.JSONArray can not be converted to JSONObject

Passing the code: `Log.i ("URL", "Request URL" + url );` send me this error

> I / URL: request url https://ipucsegundaalgarrobo.000webhostapp.com/diezmo15.php?nd=5&fd=2019-05-13&db=500000&sb1=500000&d1=105000.0&sb2=395000.0&d2=19750.0&sb3=375250.0&d3=0.0&d4=0.0&sb4=0.0&d5=7505.0&sb5=367745.0&d6=3677.449951171875&td=135932.453125&dn=364067.5625

and this is the logcat:

> d/Volley: [142] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request = <[]

I thank you in advance for any information you may offer me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your server is giving back `JsonArray` i.e :`$json` is an array, not `JsonObject`, as you have made `JsonObjectRequest` just change that to  [JsonArrayRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#java) or [StringRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple).